# Creating a table that uses all available space

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

Is there a way to use tabular or some other method to create a table that expands to use the entire available space?  So if I created a table with 4 rows, each row would use 25% of the space.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the table to expand horizontally or vertically as much as possible? (Talking about rows implies vertical growth, which is unusual and makes the question interesting.)

Comment: I was originally interested in having it expand both horizontally and vertically, but I think using tabularx will be a better solution.  Still curious about the vertical expansion though.

Comment: use `tabularht` and additional `p`-columns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible with `\usepackage{tabularx}`

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ XXXX }
  \hline
  label 1 & label 2 & label 3 & label 4 \\
  \hline
  item 1  & item 2  & item 3  & item 4  \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
```

I modified the code to add space vertically

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
  \newcommand\myvspace [2]{  \vrule width0pt height#1 depth#2}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ XXXX }
  \hline
\myvspace{1cm}{1cm} label 1 & label 2 & label 3 & label 4 \\
  \hline
 \myvspace{2cm}{2cm}\begin{minipage}{2cm}
 this is a long text and I need some place
 \end{minipage}
 & item 2  & item 3  & item 4  \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there anything that will also space it out vertically?

Comment: @Shane : what you need exactly ? For just adapting the height of rows, I use `cellspace.sty` but something like `\setlength\extrarowheight{4pt}` is possible, if you want to set the height of each rows, you can use the `strut` method, or `\renewcommand\arraystrech{1.5}`. For the entire available space horizontally , I forgot the environment tablularc. Finally, If you are an adept of TikZ like me, you can use TikZ for this kind of things.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood this correctly:

```
\vbox to\vsize{\everycr={\noalign{\vskip 2pt plus 1\vsize}}
  \halign to\hsize{&#\hfil\tabskip=1em plus 1\hsize\cr
  Sup? & These & are & going & to & space & out \cr
  Likewise & for & the & rows & which & are \cr
  Going & to & space & out & trying & to \cr
  fill & out & the & page \cr
  }
}
\bye
```

[image]